# Does the GNOME 3.x Desktop support Onedrive for Business?

Tags: gnome, 20.04

I'm aware the you can add 'online accounts' on the gnome desktop. I've seen many sources saying it supports Onedrive. Because of how Onedrive for business is slightly different, would adding a Onedrive for Business account work like a personal account?

Comment: Did you try and see if it works?

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi I haven't installed Ubuntu on the computer in question yet and my other PC runs 20.04 server. I'm going to live boot